# Contact-Form7 element's background when ERROR occurs

Tags: css, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am searching the net for a suitable answer since a week ... so its time to ask you, guys! I am working with Contact Form 7 (w "Conditional Fields for CF7" plugin) and I am trying to tailor its appearance in CSS.

And that's where my problem is; when there is an error with the sumbission (eg. some required fields were not filled) than CF7 switches to "error mode" and changes the background color of the wrongly filled forms according to the theme's color palette.
But that creates a weird situation where the form's background color and the individual form-elements' background color are the same!
This is especially disturbing when filling out the form on a mobile device.

Can someone help me how to set in CSS the background color of the elements in case of any fill-out ERROR?

thanks,
Adam[image]

Answer (score 1):

To change the background color of the form elements when there is an error with submission in Contact Form 7, you can add custom CSS to your WordPress theme.

```
.wpcf7-not-valid input[type="text"],
.wpcf7-not-valid input[type="email"],
.wpcf7-not-valid textarea {
    background-color: #f8d7da; /* Change this to your desired background color */
}
```

I've used the class .wpcf7-not-valid to target the form elements that have validation errors. Then, I've used CSS selectors to target specific input types like text, email, and text area. You can adjust the background color value (#f8d7da in this example) to match your desired color.